# C# - Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, string, verbatim-string

I have a database table that containing file paths of excel files that I import using a C# script.

The script works fine unless the filepath contains spaces e.g. `C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls` and I get an `Illegal characters in path` error message. Unfortunately I am not able to change the file names at the source.

If I hard code the file path to be as below it works fine.

```
String Filepath = @"C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls";
```

How do I alter this so I can include a string variable that will store the filepath from the database e.g.

```
String Filepath = //Code to get FilePath from database

StringCorrectedFilePath = @+FilePath;
```

Thanks in advance of any help

**Edit**: Issue is caused by files that start with a number creating invalid escape sequence. e.g. `C:\Temp\20160611 My Excel File.xls`

**Edit 2**: SOLVED - Error was caused by carriage return characters appearing after the file extension. Please see my answer for the solution.

Comment: If it works with spaces when hard-coding the variable that means that the file path you're getting from the database probably doesn't actually contain spaces.  What is the actual value you're getting from the database?

Comment: There are definitely spaces in the file path, I am looking at the database table now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you do this

```
String Filepath = @"C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls";
```

or this

```
String Filepath = "C:\\Temp\\My Excel File.xls";
```

the string stored in memory is just `C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls`, whatever the debugger may tell you. So when you read some string from somewhere (database, file, user input, ...) you don't need to "escape" backslashes. So just use that string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But its not the backslashes causing the issue, its when the file path contains spaces e.g. This file will work "C:\Temp\MyExcelFile.xls" but this one will not "C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls"

Comment: Apologies, ignore my previous comment. I've got more information. The problem only occurs when the filename starts with a number i.e. "c:\temp\20160611 My Excel File.xls"

Comment: @SimonTindall How are you using that path? You should add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, turns out the illegal characters were carriage returns appearing after the file extension. I wouldnt have found the solution if it wasnt for your pointers and i've upvoted accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

[Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars)

```
FilePath = string.Concat(FilePath.Split(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can replace blank space with `%20` character and while retrieving replace back with blank space again like (you may as well choose to use regular expression for the same)

```
String Filepath = @"C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls";
Filepath = Filepath.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

While retrieving back

```
string mypath = pathyouhavegotfromDB.Replace("%20", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put quotation marks around the path with spaces.

```
string filepath = @"C:\Temp\My Excel File.xls";            
filepath = $"\"{filepath}\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help, I tried all of these and unfortunately they didn't work which led me to believe that the issue wasn't what I originally thought.

It turns out that the files causing the `Illegal characters in path` all had carriage return characters at the end of the file name, after the file extension.

To resolve this I used the following code and now it works perfectly

```
FilePath = FilePath.TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String StringCorrectedFilePath = @""+ Filepath;
```